# Mac OS X permissions to create a zip file

Tags: php, macos, permissions, apache2

After searching the internet find an answer I've decided to ask for help directly.

I am running mac os x 10.7, PHP, Apache and MySQL.  I am trying to let a user select files from a form have them zipped and sent to the individual.  At first PHP couldn't even create a file.  I found the following:

```
sudo chmod -R +a "_www allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" ~/Sites
```

Which allowed me to create a file.  But when I try to create a zip I get some unknown extension being appended at the end and 2 files are being created.  So not knowing what was wrong I thought I would just find the file by opening the directory and forcibly renaming it back to *.zip.  I have checked the file after renaming manually and it seems to be fine.

I get the following error:

```
Warning: rename(tmp/RosenData082112-1102.zip.ohoKRw,RosenData082112-1102.zip) [function.rename]: Permission denied in /Users/mmcri/Sites/rosenlab/download.php on line 42

ls -le reveals this to the files:
-rw-------+ 1 _www  staff  43775 Aug 21 11:02 RosenData082112-1102.zip.1qJUE4
 0: user:_www inherited allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
-rw-------+ 1 _www  staff  43775 Aug 21 11:02 RosenData082112-1102.zip.ohoKRw
 0: user:_www inherited allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

Here is the PHP code section making the zip file:

```
if(extension_loaded('zip'))
{ 
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $zipname = "RosenData".date("mdy-Hi").".zip";

   if($zip->open($direct.$zipname, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === TRUE)
   {
       foreach($filelist as $file)
            $zip->addFile($path.$file,$file) or die ("Error adding file: $file");
       $zip->close();
}
 // Random stuff below
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of the `$direct` variable?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have permissions to write on that folder in Mac?

Try with fopen instead of ZipArchive.

Comment: Yes I do.  After I added the chmod statement from my original post the code below works.   

`if($fp = fopen("temp.txt", w))  fwrite($fp, "Are you working?");`

This creates a file.  What I don't understand is why `.ohoKRw` is being added to the end of the file and actually 2 files with different "extensions" are being added.

Comment: The file runs.  And here is the directory tmp/ contents with ls -l <br/><br/>
    
-rw-------+ 1 _www  staff   0 Aug 23 21:30 RosenData082312-2130.zip.7ZYgvh
-rw-------+ 1 _www  staff   0 Aug 23 21:30 RosenData082312-2130.zip.B5daZ3
-rw-r--r--+ 1 _www  staff  16 Aug 23 21:30 temp.txt<br/><br/>

Comment: Hmm.. Please try CHMODing the file through an FTP client.

Comment: Do you mean the zip file or PHP script that is making the zip?  I only ask because the zip is supposed to be made and then sent to the user via download dialog box.